# New 'About' Page

Tags: discussion

For those who may have missed it, they're [rolling out a new "quick start" page to every site in the Stack Exchange Network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163254/were-rolling-out-a-new-quick-start-guide-to-help-new-users-learn-the-basics).

[Ours](https://android.stackexchange.com/about) seems to have gone live recently.

Reading the whole thing *also* earns you a Badge.

---

They've finally also [blogged about it](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/01/about-page-2-0-the-quickstartening/).

Comment: Looks very nice! :) Clean and simple! Animated slide-outs is neat!

Comment: I noticed it a while back - I flows really well on my Nexus ;-)

Comment: This looks great!

Comment: i read it all, i didn't get a badge. at least not one that I was notified about.

Comment: @Ryan: I see that you got the [Informed](http://android.stackexchange.com/badges/90/informed?userid=1951) badge.

Comment: hmmm, interesting, usually i get a notification about a new badge.

Answer (score 1):

Looks good, but I miss the info graphic with the 4 circles Wiki, Blog, Digg and ? where Stackexchange is the point in the middle. It always reminded me that I can use Stackexchange sites to document Q&A that may be relevant to other users as well by simply answering my own question in one step.

Comment: Perhaps they have decided it's time to stop defining themselves in terms of other sites :P